# Displaying Bootstrap Collapsing Navigation Bar in a new row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<div class = "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
    <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#">Blog</a></li>
        <li class = "dropdown">
            <a href = "#" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown">Social Media<b class= "caret"></b></a>
            <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href = "#">Twitter</a></li>
                <li><a href = "#">Facebook</a></li>
                <li><a href = "#">LinkedIn</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is the result:

[image]

How to place the collapsing navbar in a new line?

Edit:
I want to display my navigation bar in a new line as in following picture.

[image]

Comment: It's not clear for me what you want. Please explain more

Comment: This is working as expected - [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/auo3t6c5/). Can you please post your complete HTML snippet for the `navbar` element and explain, what exactly you are having trouble with, otherwise it is hard to tell what is going on here.

Comment: @EhsanAbd: Can you see the edit? I'm new to this community.

Comment: @DavidDomain Please... see the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Try the sample of code for Collapsible Navigation Bar to be appeared in a new row.
```

```css
.heading {
  text-align: center;
}
.navbar .navbar-collapse {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 heading">
      <h1>Heading goes here</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
          </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the [sample PEN](http://codepen.io/YaserAliPeedikakkal/pen/XXedYV), hope this will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ldepaula/z06yc406/) I set up

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#">Blog</a></li>
        <li class = "dropdown">
            <a href = "#" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown">Social Media<b class= "caret"></b></a>
            <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href = "#">Twitter</a></li>
                <li><a href = "#">Facebook</a></li>
                <li><a href = "#">LinkedIn</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Here is the result:

[image]

What is going on is that your class **navHeaderCollapse** is probably effecting on your code.

Please post your current CSS class so we can take a look at it.

Good luck!

Comment: I see the problem. There is no class called navHeaderCollapse in my bootstrap css file. What should I do?

Comment: If  you don't have it, why is it on your HTML code you posted with your question? Again, post the CSS code you've written (if you have some) and inspect your element right clicking it and choosing inspect element. And please, don't negative answers if  you didn't post the necessary code for answering it.

Comment: I learnt this from a youtube tutorial, might be a outdated channel and seems like bootstrap css class has been changed (I downloaded the bootstrap from http://getbootstrap.com/)

Comment: @Idepaula3 Can you please tell me the use of your 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1' ?

Comment: @Lalinda Sampath This is not my notation. It's bootstrap's notation for using javascript to modify and add actions to the element in the case, collapsing it in this case.

Comment: Thanks.. I figured out the problem